# React function not being invoked, unless calling it directly

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to generate a component dynamically and render the component as a return from a function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './helloWorld';

export default class BaseComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.getFields = this.getFields.bind(this)
}

getFields() {
  let temp = { hi: 'Hello', world: 'World!' }
  const test = temp.map(function(val, i) {
                return <HelloWorld key={i} val={val} />
              })
  return test
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
                {this.getFields}
        </div>
   );
}
}
```

But this function is not being invoked unless I use {this.getFields()} in my render method. Why can't I just use {this.getFields}, as that is bound in the constructor and hence should render the value. What am I missing?

Comment: because you need to call that method, otherwise how it will return the result, function name will return the body of the function, check by using `console.log(this.getFields);` to get the result you need to call by using `()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the method from render function to use the returned value and not assign it and hence you need `{this.getFields()}`

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
                {this.getFields()}
        </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to render {this.getFields()}? I have bound this getFields in the constructor, so when I call this.getFields, because it is already bound to the constructor. So, is there a way for me to just use {this.getFields} in the render method?

Comment: @Mona, when you want to get the returned value of a function what do you do, do you just assign a refernce of it like console.log(myfunc) or you call it, like console.log(myfunc()). It is a similar case here. I hope this example makes you understand. If not, then try console.log(this.getFields) in render method and see what is the result that you get as opposed to console.log(this.getFields())

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function:

`{this.getFields()}`